# Is there a way to wipe an individual NFT and mint a new one on Hedera? or will all tokens with the same ID be wiped?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

For Hedera NFTs, if a user wants to have the ability to clawback an NFT (wipe and mint a new one) are you able to perform that operation on a Serial Number basis or is it only at the Token ID level?

E.g. if User A owns two NFTs of the same token ID can you only wipe all tokens or can you specify NFT X?

Answer (score 0):

The TokenAccountWipe is on a per-serial-number basis. It's also true for burn (i.e., you burn NFTs from the treasury by serial number)
But when minting an NFT, you cannot specify the serial number you want; it's always greater than the last serial number minted.